# Do math on html data - Add all contents of <li> tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, math

I have the following html:

```
<div id="list">
<ul>
<li>45.00</li>
<li>45.00</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Is there any way to take the contents of those list items and add them using javascript/jQuery?

Comment: Show us what you tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: I haven't tried anything, I could not find anything on Google and don't know javascript.

Comment: I'm trying to learn and had a question, no need to be rude.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a jQuery method that totals to a global variable.

```
var total = 0.0;

$('#list li').each(function() {
    total += parseFloat($(this).html());
});
```

Answer (score 3):

No need for Jquery.

```
const listItems = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('#list li'))

const sum = listItems.reduce(function(sum, el) {
    return sum + parseFloat(el.innerText)
}, 0)

console.log(sum)
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9evgpu88/

Answer (score 2):

you can get all elements content using `each`

```
var sum=0;
$('#list li').each(function(){
    sum+=parseFloat($(this).html());
})
console.log(sum)
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gy26jsox/1/

Comment: his values are floats, not integers.

Answer (score 1):

Use `$( "li" ).each();` like :

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 var sum=0;
 $("li").each(function() {
      sum+=parseFloat(($(this).text()));
 });
    //alert(sum);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="list">
<ul>
<li>45.00</li>
<li>45.00</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var result = 0;
$('#list li').each(function () {
    result += +$(this).text();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the script element:

```
<script>
var l = document.getElementById('list');
var a = l.children[0].innerHTML;
var b = l.children[1].innerHTML;
alert(parseFloat(a)+parseFloat(b));
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

here is one way with simple javascript: https://jsfiddle.net/7ku7qvfx/11/

```
<div id="list">
  <ul>
    <li id="num1">45.00</li>
    <li id="num2">45.00</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<script>
  var num1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("num1").innerHTML);
  var num2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("num2").innerHTML);
  var num3 = num1 + num2;
  alert(num3);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using below mentioned code in Javascript, we can achieve expected result for any number of li elements

```
var matches = document.querySelectorAll("div li");

var total = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < matches.length; i++) {
  total = total + (matches[i].innerHTML * 1);

}

alert(total)
```

http://codepen.io/pen/